# Can't detect select box name when POST-ing

Tags: jquery, forms, post, http-post

I have a simple select box:

```
<select name="rims" id="rims">
  <option value="1">Silver</option>
  <option value="2">Golden</option>
  <option value="3">Platinum</option>
  <option value="4">Custom</option>
</select>
```

I use jQuery to detect when user's made a selection:

```
    $("#rims").change(function() {

        $("#new_div").load("./models/create-report.php?selected=rims", { value: $(this).val() }, function() {

        });
    });
```

**PROBLEM:** The only thing I get in $_POST variable is the selected value, but I cannot know if it came from "rims" select box:

```
array
  'value' => string '2' (length=1)
```

So when I add another select box, and user makes a selection, that value overwrites the one above.

**QUESTION:** How can I get the name of the select box too, so that $_POST can hold choices from multiple select boxes?

Comment: how do you make your ajax call?

Comment: I too am having a hard time following you, when do you want to have access to the select element's name attribute?

Comment: @Daniel A. White - example code updated.

Comment: @Scruffy The Janitor: I want access to it from my php script which is loaded on .change

Comment: @Freelancer since it is being called from `#rims` onchange event, can't you assume that its coming from the `name='rims'` element and just pass it as a value?

Comment: @Scruffy The Janitor: Yes I can, the value is stored in $_POST['value'].   But when I add another select box on screen, also listened by jQuery, the change in that select box goes to $_POST['value'] overriding previous one. What I'd like is to have values from both or multiple select boxes available in $_POST at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the id/name to the post information.

```
$("#rims").change(function() {

    $("#new_div").load("./models/create-report.php?selected=rims",{ "value": $(this).val(), "id": $(this).attr('id'), "name": $(this).attr('name') }, function() {

    });
});
```